# How should i store newlines in a MySQL database?

Tags: php, html, mysql, newline

I'm going around and around in circles in my mind trying to decide how best I should store newlines in a MySQL database.

A bit of background; the user is asked to complete a textarea. This has to stored in a MySQL database before being read back out and the content included in an HTML email.

Should I store them as:

1) String literal - surely this is dangerous and bad practice

2) As a string with `\r\n` in - when I read this back out of the database its read as 4 characters so `nl2br()` fails to correctly replace them.

3) As HTML `<br />` - as it has to be html entity encoded to be stored it ends up being stored as `&lt;br /&gt;` so when it gets to the email `<br />` is printed rather than an actual newline. Passing it through `html_entity_decode()` would decode other characters that need to be encoded.

Any help  grately appreciated.

Comment: "String literal - surely this is dangerous and bad practice" — Why would it be?

Comment: string literal `\r\n` is newline and represent 2 characters. But if single quotes are used `'\r\n'` they will not be recognized by `nl2br()`.

Comment: I'd say that not escaping user input is always bad practice and opens you up to a wealth of vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Store it as it is but **escape first**. This is your option 1. When you need to present this data apply whatever function you need to format it.  If you need to show it in HTML use `nl2br()` and `htmlentities()` functions. That'll work for mail also.

If you have a text area data like this,

```
$text="Hello Sir,
I am Robert'); Drop table students; --
.....
Yours most obedient pupil
.....";
```

Just store it as it is after you escape it, or use a prepared statement.

```
$text = $mysqli->real_escape_string($text);
```

Comment: Agreed, data should be as raw as possible in the database (once injection has been taken care of). Then, you can pick it up and safely assume nothing is going to mess with how you present the data except for what you did yourself.

Comment: This is more akin to my option 2 to be honest. `real_escape_string` converts what is a newline into the 4 character string '\n\r' meaning that on reading it out of storage again, nl2br() ignores it. An option here would be to do a `str_replace()` to pick up all occurences of `\n \r \r\n \n\r` but I was hoping for a more complete solution.

Comment: @RobForrest no you're wrong. When you read this back, you will get the 2 chars `\r\n` (0x0D, 0x0A) instead of the 4 chars `"\r\n"` (and `nl2br` will be able to replace them into `<br />`

Comment: ahhh, you're right. It looks like that somewhere along the line I was escaping it twice. Thanks for all your help guys.

Answer (score 2):

use the javascript string replace function `str.replace(/\n/g,'\\n')`

to transform all newlines to escaped literals in the textarea while forming the url or post string.

Retrieving the same using PHP's `json_encode()` and displaying it through a textarea works well for me.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on application type (how you want to display your text).

If this is HTML e-mail editor - i think html format will be better.

In most CMS (content management systems) HTML format is used (joomla, wordpress, prestashop etc.), because you can just read this from database and send to browser.

Besides - you probably may need other HTML tags anyway (like `<b>` for bold or `<center>`).

I think using `\r\n` format is better for non-web applications, when data is displayed on windows form controls.

One more thing - you may store them in both ways:
- `<br>` for HTML view
- `\r\n` for HTML source (to add some newline's and make more readable html source code)

By more readable html i mean this:

```
<center>
This is header
</center>
<p>
This is paragraph.
<br>
Second line.
</p>
```

Instead of this:

```
<center>This is header</center><p>This is paragraph.<br>Second line.</p>
```