# How to use \n in a javascript string

Tags: javascript, string, arangodb, console.log

Example:

```
var i = 'Hello \n World'
console.log(i)
```

Would return:

```
Hello
World
```

and **I want it to return**

```
Hello \n World
```

not rendering the new line, as I intend to store this in a database.

---

**FOR THOSE WHO WANT TO STORE `\n` in Database**

You don't need to escape, as your Document Database will do `JSON.stringify`, I use ArangoDB and it works perfectly fine, thanks to [@PaulPro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/772035/paul)

Comment: You have to escape the escape character `\\n`

Comment: You can store newline characters in databases... There must be some other reason you want to store it as two characters instead of one.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14138706/how-should-i-store-newlines-in-a-mysql-database/14138880#14138880

Comment: @ProfessorAllman how would I do this, is there a built-in function in javascript to do this?

Comment: @Paulpro this is because \n creates news lines and can't be stored in JSON or Document database

Comment: @Lieblingsmensch When you store something in a DB you should escape it properly for the DB as you insert. It is a very bad practice to try escaping yourself in advance and can lead to major security vulnerabilities. If you are inserting JSON your DB layer should JSON.stringify its input. `JSON.stringify( 'Hello \n World' )` also gives you the correct value to store in the DB, but `JSON.stringify( 'Hello \\n World' )` will give you the wrong value because it will be double escaped then.

Comment: @Paulpro Thanks for the heads up, I'll keep that in mind

Comment: Okay after editing my code, @PaulPro is absolutely spot on, no need to escape characters as the Document Database will most likely do it for you, if not you still only have to do \n and not \\n

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You would escape the `\` with `\\`, which would tell the interpreter just to produce the character without processing it as a special character:

```js
var i = 'Hello \\n World';
console.log(i)
```

Here are all the string escape codes:

- `\0` The NUL character (\u0000)
- `\b` Backspace (\u0008)
- `\t` Horizontal tab (\u0009)
- `\n` Newline (\u000A)
- `\v` Vertical tab (\u000B)
- `\f` Form feed (\u000C)
- `\r` Carriage return (\u000D)
- `\"` Double quote (\u0022)
- `\'` Apostrophe or single quote (\u0027)
- `\\` Backslash (\u005C)
- `\x XX` The Latin-1 character specified by the two hexadecimal digits XX
- `\u XXXX` The Unicode character specified by the four hexadecimal digits XXXX

Answer (score 2):

Escape `\n` with `\\n` and store the string in DB. However, only `\n` can also be stored in DB.

Answer (score 1):

Use "\\n" instead of "\n" for this to work, same case with selenium java

```
      WebElement searchBox = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
      searchBox.sendKeys("Test \\n");
      searchBox.submit();
```